# Trying to access alias inside a custom helper throws 'Not found' message. Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, helper, aliases

For my app i've created a function that returns either a view or an already rendered view inside some json. Since i will need to use this function quite alot i made a custom helper so i can call it from every controller. however unfortunately, when i try to use another alias inside this helper it does not seem to recognize it. giving me a message that says that the alias 'Request' was not found even though i can access and use it from any controller.

I've added the helper inside de config/app.php with an alias so it's easier to access it.

This is my code:

controller:

```
use AppHelper;

class MediaController extends Controller
{

    public function index() 
    {
        return AppHelper::returnView("backend.media.index", "navigation.media.media");
    }
    ...
```

AppHelper:

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;
use Request;

class AppHelper
{
    public static function returnView($viewName, $menu, $data = []) {

        $template = $viewName.'-template';
        $view = $viewName;

        if (Request::ajax()) {
            if(isset($data->id)){
                $navigation = view('backend.navigation.right-menu')->with('id', $data->id)->with('menuItems', $menu)->render();
        } else {
        ...
```

In the helper i've also tried to call the 'Request' via its actual path but to no avail.

I've tried looking up a solution for an hour or so now but just can't seem to find it on google or on stackoverflow.

Thanks for reading.

kind regards, Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think

```
use Request;
```

is specific enough, considering the number of different `Request` classes in Laravel. You're probably looking for:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

if you want to define `Request $request` somewhere in your `AppHelper`, or the alias `Request`, available via:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```

Which should allow the use of `Request::ajax()` and similar functions.

Alternatively, you could pass the `$request` object, which is already available from any controller method, from your `MediaController` function `index()`, like:

MediaController.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function index(Request $request){
  return AppHelper::returnView($request, "backend.media.index", "navigation.media.media");
}
```

AppHelper.php

```
public static function returnView($request, $viewName, $menu, $data = []) {
  ...
  if($request->ajax()){
    ...
  }
}
```

Edit: Some caveats to the `ajax()` method:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
...
if(Request::ajax()){ ... }
```

The above should work fine, or, remove the `use` statement and reference with

```
if(\Request::ajax()){ ... }
```

When passing the `$request`, make sure it is an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request`, and `$request->ajax()` should work fine.

Comment: first of all, Thanks for your response :). trying to "use Illuminate\Http\Request;" gave me a 'request::ajax is not a static function', i tried applying your second option but gave me the same results as how i initially tried, your third option throws a 'call to undefined method ajax()' message, so unfortunately the solution does not seem to work.

Comment: Hmm... Let me try to recreate locally; see if I can debug that further. I'm pretty sure `ajax()` is available on at least one of those. Bear with me

Comment: You seem to still be having some namespacing issues. `\Request::ajax()` should work, as `\Request` will return the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;` instance. Otherwise, if you're passing it as a variable, make sure your controller has `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of it, so you're not passing an instance of the `Request` facade.

Comment: After trial and error for a couple of hours it suddenly works, i have no idea what i did but i'm gonna assume i misstyped something and your answer was actually working. Thanks for the help